# Maatwebsite Excel - how to name multiple sheets?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I've got an Maatwebsite (v3.1.25) Excel Export as follows. What is the simplest way to add a custom name for each sheet? Currently they just appear as "Worksheet", "Worksheet 1" etc.

I did see the official website's documentation, but couldn't figure out how to apply it to my specific situation.

```
class BizdevReport implements WithMultipleSheets
{


    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [
            new BizdevReportTeachers(),
            new BizdevReportClasses(),
            new BizdevReportGMV()
        ];

        return $sheets;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to help answer.

although you asked 9 months ago, but maybe this will be useful for people who need answers.

inside `BizdevReportTeachers` class, you implement `WithTitle` and add `title` function

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;

class BizdevReportTeachers implements WithTitle
{
     public function title(): string
     {
          return 'Lorem Ipsum';
     }
}
```

reference: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/multiple-sheets.html

Comment: Thanks for this - I also missed that we need to use WithTitle concern, I forked the repo and updated the documentation to make things more clear:  https://github.com/SpartnerNL/laravel-excel-docs/pull/194

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there . Just add the name you required to sheets array like below

class BizdevReport implements WithMultipleSheets
{

```
public function sheets(): array
{
    $sheets = [
      'BizdevReportTeachers' =>  new BizdevReportTeachers(),
      'BizdevReportClasses' =>  new BizdevReportClasses(),
      'BizdevReportGMV' =>  new BizdevReportGMV()
    ];

    return $sheets;
  }
}
```

Thats all.